# Autolayout warning tableview cell

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I am building a chat layout and i have a table view and custom chat cell by adding constraint programmatically but i am getting the autolayout warning

In my `ChatMessageCell` i have a enum `Style` to determine the chat layout direction leading or trailing

I have `messageLabel` which has top, bottom, leading or trailing anchor to the `UITableViewCell`and `width` less than equal to 250

I have `view` which has leading, trailing, bottom and top anchor to the `messageLabel` view, `setMessageLayout` method active or deactive the leading or trailing anchor of the `view`

> Autolayout Warning

```
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000039a3c00 UILabel:0x7ff54cc34b20'Hello how are you'.width <= 250   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000039a3e80 H:[UILabel:0x7ff54cc34b20'Hello how are you']-(16)-|   (active, names: '|':iOSChatApp.ChatMessageCell:0x7ff54d087600'cell_leading' )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000039a3e30 iOSChatApp.ChatMessageCell:0x7ff54d087600'cell_leading'.leading == UILabel:0x7ff54cc34b20'Hello how are you'.leading - 16   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000039afca0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' iOSChatApp.ChatMessageCell:0x7ff54d087600'cell_leading'.width == 375   (active)>"
)
```

> ChatMessageCell

```
class ChatMessageCell: UITableViewCell {

enum Style {
    case leading
    case trailing
}


private var style: Style!
private let messageLbl = UILabel()
private let view = UIView()
private var leadingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
private var trailingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

var message: ChatMessage! {
    didSet {

        messageLbl.text = message.message
        setMessageLayout(with: message.sender == "User1" ? .leading : .trailing)

    }
}

override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9490196078, green: 0.9450980392, blue: 0.9529411765, alpha: 1)

    messageLbl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    messageLbl.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Book", size: 17)
    messageLbl.numberOfLines = 0

    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.layer.cornerRadius = 5

    addSubview(view)
    addSubview(messageLbl)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messageLbl.topAnchor, constant: -16),
        bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messageLbl.bottomAnchor, constant: 16),
        messageLbl.widthAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualToConstant: 250)
    ])


    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messageLbl.topAnchor, constant: -8),
        view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messageLbl.bottomAnchor, constant: 8),
        view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messageLbl.leadingAnchor, constant: -8),
        view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messageLbl.trailingAnchor, constant: 8),
    ])

    leadingConstraint = leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messageLbl.leadingAnchor, constant: -16)
    trailingConstraint = trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: messageLbl.trailingAnchor, constant: 16)

    leadingConstraint.isActive = true
    trailingConstraint.isActive = false
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}


func setMessageLayout(with style: Style) {

    messageLbl.textColor = style == .leading ? .black : .white
    view.backgroundColor = style == .leading ? .white : #colorLiteral(red: 0.06274509804, green: 0.6039215686, blue: 0.3019607843, alpha: 1)

    leadingConstraint.isActive = style == .leading ? true : false
    trailingConstraint.isActive = style == .trailing ? true : false

}

}
```

> My Layout

[image: ChatLayout1]
[image: ChatLayout2]

Comment: Why are you doing this in code?

Comment: [Go to the link](https://www.wtfautolayout.com/) and paste your autolayout warning, figure out what is conflicting. Your width and trailing constraints are conflicting.

Comment: @Adrian why you shouldn't?

Comment: @jackjay Wow this tool is simply amazing.

Comment: @JayLee Autolayout warnings are troublesome to understand in xcode console. This tool helps a lot to figure out the issue.

Answer (score 1):

According to your Autolayout warning, messageLabel's width and leading are conflicting.

The warning is telling that both status are active

```
 (
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000039a3c00 UILabel:0x7ff54cc34b20'Hello how are you'.width <= 250   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000039a3e80 H:[UILabel:0x7ff54cc34b20'Hello how are you']-(16)-|   (active, names: '|':iOSChatApp.ChatMessageCell:0x7ff54d087600'cell_leading' )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000039a3e30 iOSChatApp.ChatMessageCell:0x7ff54d087600'cell_leading'.leading == UILabel:0x7ff54cc34b20'Hello how are you'.leading - 16   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000039afca0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' iOSChatApp.ChatMessageCell:0x7ff54d087600'cell_leading'.width == 375   (active)>"
)
```

If you read warning carefully, the console may recommend you what to remove.